# Can I disable continuation of comments to the next line in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, if I'm typing a comment in a code file, and I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it automatically makes the newline a comment, too.

For instance, in a Ruby file:

```
# I manually typed the pound at the start of this line and hit enter.
# This line formatted itself this way automatically.
```

Generally, this is what I want, but not always. **How can I temporarily turn off this auto-commenting behavior?**

Comment: By temporarily, do you want a a command that does it a single time, or set some option that will last for a few commands until you turn it back on? Possible cross site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896003/how-do-i-stop-vim-from-auto-creating-comments-on-enter-press

Comment: I've seen it elsewhere but I'll add it here: "Whoever thought this was a good idea as a default should have their fingers broken."

Comment: This [wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion) talks about this.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
:set formatoptions-=cro
```

From [`:help fo-table`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table):

```
You can use the 'formatoptions' option  to influence how Vim formats text.
'formatoptions' is a string that can contain any of the letters below.  The
default setting is "tcq".  You can separate the option letters with commas for
readability.

letter  meaning when present in 'formatoptions'

t       Auto-wrap text using textwidth
c       Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
        leader automatically.
r       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
        <Enter> in Insert mode.
o       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
        'O' in Normal mode.
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This behavior was bothering me-- I came from unix vi to Linux vim. For googlers: For **permanent use**, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076592/vim-set-formatoptions-being-lost and enter this line into /etc/vimrc:`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal formatoptions-=cro`

Comment: Didn't help; typing `/**<ESC>o` still adds a star on the next line.

Comment: Doesn't work. z

Comment: Also didn't work for me. I believe the issue is that `-=cro` only works if `formatoptions` contains the flags exactly in this order. `set formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o` works better for me.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer here that works.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: If you're coming here from C or C++ and don't want `//` comments at the end of a line to continue after pressing Enter, use `set formatoptions+=/` (or the autocmd equivalent in your .vimrc) (found this answer from a search for "vim C disable indented multi-line c++ comment")

Comment: -= did not work for me on RHEL8. only formatoptions= worked, next step removing brace highlighting

Comment: @MartinvonWittich that does not work for me, either, on vim 7.4.629 (RHEL6).

Comment: @bgStack15 *that* works.

Comment: on an RHEL-like, I needed @Wenfang-Du version of this answer to match every file type.

Answer (score 15):

Temporarily setting the 'paste' option may do what you want, but it also disables a lot of other Vim features:

Use `:set paste` to turn it on and `:set nopaste` to turn it off. Alternatively, you can use `:set paste!` to toggle it.

See also:

```
:help 'paste'
:help 'pastetoggle'
```

(Those commands are typed with the single-quotes.)

Comment: `:set paste` to turn it on and `:set nopaste` to turn it off

Comment: alternatively you can use `:set paste!` to toggle it TRUE and FALSE

Answer (score 11):

An alternative is to just hit `ctrl-w` after you pressed `enter`. This deletes the previous word (e.g. `#` or `//`) when in insert mode. In fact, `ctrl-w` is a pretty universal shortcut in most applications.

Comment: > In fact, `ctrl-w` is a pretty universal shortcut in most applications

It means "Close Window" (or tab) in most applications I use. Sucks for vim bindings in jupyter, e.g.

Answer (score 5):

I enter non-formatted plain new lines with `<CR>`.

When I want to continue typing the next line in the commented block I just use the <kbd>O</kbd> key as usual.

Try this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <cr> :set paste<cr>o<esc>:set nopaste<cr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `<CR>`? A particular key?

Comment: CR stands for carriage return. On the computers I have used it has been mapped to the Enter key.

Answer (score 4):

To **permanently** disable this behavior, add `autocmd FileType * set formatoptions-=cro` in your `.vimrc`/`init.vim`.

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up with this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>o o<Esc>^Da
nnoremap <Leader>O O<Esc>^Da
```

It appends a new line, deletes everything already inserted there, and leaves the cursor in insert mode in the indented column, without messing with the format options.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) and some of its derivatives.

On a Debian distribution Vim defaults are unreasonable. They are located in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` and applied after(!) `/etc/vim/vimrc` is run. The only way to tell Vim not to use its defaults is to ensure `~/.vimrc` exists even if it is blank. Vim on startup tries to read from `.vimrc`, but if the file is not found it applies the defaults which brings a lot of undesirable behavior e.g. mouse integration, copy-paste quirks, comment auto-wrap, etc.

On Debian you can fix ALL that by simply running `touch ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 1):

This just makes it one line command which when you run this, it will disable continuation of comment permanently

```
echo 'au FileType * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: This answer would be better simply as: *Add `autocmd FileType * set formatoptions-=cro` to your `.vimrc` file.*  But +1 non-the-less - this was the only answer that worked for me here! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to temporary disable this feature, I think the easiest way is to make a key map. `<C-u>` can delete content of current line to the beginning, keep indent space, so I created a key map in my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <C-CR> "\<CR>\<C-u>"
```

This map is for insert mode, you can create a normal mode key map if you want, like below:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr> <C-CR> "o\<C-u>"
```